# Unable to update Phonegap android target from 19 to android target 20

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I am using phonegap/cordova 3.3 and android 4.4 with android targets 19 and 20. I recently installed the target-20. So now i want the Phonegap projects to use android latest target 20. I executed the command phonegap platform update android , i do not see any update in the project.
AndroidManifest.xml still contains

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

can anyone please help me here ?
regards,
Swapna

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the API in the Android SDK Manager. 
Can you paste a screen shot of your Android SDK Manager?
You should see something similar to the below screenshot in your SDK Manager
[image]

Comment: Yes i have installed the using SDK manager. i have similar packages installed.

Comment: @user3776320 what tools(IDE) are you using for development? Are you using Eclipse IDE for development?

Comment: i could resolve it. I think i had not tried creating a project again after tupdating the project.properties in the .cordova. This can be closed now

Answer (score 0):

i could resolve it. I think i had not tried creating a project again after tupdating the project.properties in the .cordova. After updating the target=android-20, create new Phonegap Project and do a local build, i can see the targetSdkVersion as 20.

This can be closed now.